# Linux kernel module not loading firmware file for bluetooth adapter

Tags: fedora, bluetooth, realtek

I am running FC35 and just plugged in a USB dongle bluetooth adapter based on the RealTek 8761b chipset.  FC35 ships with the following firmware in the /lib/firmware/rtl_bt directory:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    80 Oct 28 09:19 rtl8761b_config.bin.xz
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 21460 Oct 28 09:19 rtl8761b_fw.bin.xz
```

On bootup dmesg shows the following for the dongle:

```
[    1.218007] usb 7-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2550, idProduct=8761, bcdDevice= 2.00
[    1.218013] usb 7-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    1.218016] usb 7-1: Product: Bluetooth Radio
[    1.218019] usb 7-1: Manufacturer: Realtek
[    1.218021] usb 7-1: SerialNumber: 00E04C239987
```

Now if I run bluetoothctl and issue the list command I see:

```
Controller 00:E0:4C:19:73:74 myhost.com [default]
```

In bluetoothctl I tell the BT dongle to scan for devices, but it finds nothing.  I even brought several devices in range, set a BT keyboard to pair, but still nothing.

Should my dmesg contain a message about loading firmware for the 8761b?  (I don't see any such message) - perhaps a clue?

---

UPDATE:

Using modinfo I notice the kernel module does not reference the firmware file found on my system!  (notice it references rtl8761a but not rtl8761b)   Why not - is this what I need to fix:

```
[root@myhost rtl_bt]# lsmod | grep rtl
btrtl                  28672  1 btusb
bluetooth             671744  35 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
[root@myhost rtl_bt]# modinfo btrtl
filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.10-200.fc35.x86_64/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btrtl.ko.xz
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8852au_config.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8852au_fw.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8822b_config.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8822b_fw.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8821a_config.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8821a_fw.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8761a_config.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8761a_fw.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8723ds_config.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8723ds_fw.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8723bs_config.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8723bs_fw.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8723a_fw.bin
license:        GPL
version:        0.1
description:    Bluetooth support for Realtek devices ver 0.1
author:         Daniel Drake <drake@endlessm.com>
srcversion:     AF29B80A444B91C5F9A1DD9
depends:        bluetooth
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           btrtl
vermagic:       5.15.10-200.fc35.x86_64 SMP mod_unload
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Fedora kernel signing key
sig_key:        73:A5:B1:60:F6:91:8E:75:8E:9E:2D:95:52:3A:82:2E:A3:46:87:D7
sig_hashalgo:   sha256
signature:      2F:6D:F3:52:84:85:A0:54:91:25:B8:0C:91:5F:52:98:02:E9:76:36:
                74:72:E6:7B:97:C2:5B:36:03:C2:C0:78:B6:9F:F9:D0:BE:5E:57:7B:
                D6:C8:A0:B6:22:DA:9D:CE:19:CF:E1:50:05:BF:02:AA:8D:08:5A:F2:
                6C:A0:6E:00:1A:B2:A8:61:94:33:8C:CC:B0:71:93:4D:23:DE:79:59:
                66:EE:3F:99:DE:F6:D7:DC:78:B6:68:B2:0D:96:CF:54:36:BC:14:3F:
                29:CF:1A:1E:8B:3A:46:FA:6A:9E:CB:76:6F:55:C1:6B:9B:C5:97:F7:
                45:71:45:C3:74:6A:E9:BE:22:F7:E2:26:00:2E:AE:3C:D4:42:F8:CA:
                77:35:91:A9:E3:94:2E:C2:A6:10:91:69:5B:EA:82:57:47:FF:31:AB:
                65:33:74:AA:39:5A:85:08:99:9E:96:80:23:2A:79:20:41:7C:22:94:
                55:C6:1C:A4:A9:F6:D8:7A:4C:6A:F9:25:71:B9:F7:2E:94:D3:2C:7C:
                B3:93:95:BD:98:C1:D9:B8:63:67:C9:7F:5B:93:1E:DD:F4:42:A3:07:
                30:0E:40:86:80:55:9E:44:51:70:0C:F1:CB:86:56:F7:13:60:55:18:
                16:50:08:66:0B:4F:6B:F1:75:70:C6:80:F0:39:3D:6F:69:04:97:54:
                61:09:B3:F8:F1:89:43:E6:19:CB:F5:55:18:1B:DC:98:FA:1D:41:2F:
                64:64:69:4A:5F:51:25:04:CE:16:C7:6D:B6:35:79:A9:CE:C6:96:D6:
                13:9D:C9:A2:9C:55:AB:83:F8:DC:27:F8:09:72:B8:C9:A2:1F:66:E2:
                6A:6D:DE:EF:3D:DB:9A:A4:81:2F:F1:AD:E8:30:80:4C:22:CA:E2:6A:
                DD:5D:D3:78:6E:A2:24:FC:69:2F:BE:AC:A4:D7:57:00:77:2F:87:57:
                4B:20:BF:45:F8:26:7B:93:D0:BC:36:AC:8F:12:DF:22:43:02:41:78:
                8D:9F:79:46:A3:8C:C4:D7:BC:51:09:A7:8E:2B:8E:4C:EB:5A:8F:FF:
                12:C6:AE:25:32:BF:73:39:97:FD:8C:FF:57:F8:FF:D9:D8:55:98:6F:
                F3:3E:55:57:CF:2A:AD:AC:E8:0F:27:F5:79:47:7F:71:2C:A3:27:84:
                CD:8C:D9:ED:DD:BA:75:87:54:FE:6D:DB:ED:43:15:17:01:8E:9D:3C:
                6F:C1:BE:0D:CD:C3:E8:48:93:89:2C:DB:00:48:F4:E9:60:F7:C2:20:
                2B:17:26:14:44:69:03:F6:57:63:D0:0B:CD:2A:1E:95:71:C9:8D:46:
                FD:02:08:BB:FF:DA:A4:D8:BE:86:FB:A5
```